# TsVector in postgres is returning uncertain results when used with single alphabets

Tags: java, postgresql, autosuggest, tsvector

I am trying to write a autosuggest API using tsVectors in postgres. When I am running the following query:

````
select to_tsvector('english', 'This is a test') @@  to_tsquery('tes:*');```
````

Postgres is returning `true`, which is expected. But when I am running the following one,

```
select to_tsvector('english', 'This is test') @@  to_tsquery('t:*');
```

Postgres is returning `false`, which is unexpected. Does tsQueries don't work when used with a single alphabet followed by an wildcard operator ?
Is there a solution for this situation ?

Comment: The single character, `t`, is a stopword in my copy of `/usr/share/postgresql/10/tsearch_data/english.stop`.